# runtimeerror: strides() called on an undefined Tensor

Tags: pytorch, torchscript

```
model.eval()
trace_script_module = torch.jit.script(model, (image1, image2))
trace_script_module.save("a.pt")
```

> meet runtimeerror: strides() called on an undefined Tensor

I try to move model and input to cpu, but has no change. And I delete `trace_script_module.save("a.pt")`, there is no error, so just the `.save()` function error.
But I also can't find where used `strides()`.